# Name that node #2

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, graph-theory

What is the value of the unknown node?

[image]

Previous

- [Name that node #1 (Beginner's Level Puzzle)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97637/name-that-node-1-beginners-level-puzzle)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the ? is

> 101

My workings:

> In the beginning, I found 2 nodes with relatively smaller values to start with: $7$ & $28$.
> I tried $7\times28$ which gave me a result of $196$.
> Since $196$ is sort of close to the number $161$ on the edge, I tried $196-161$ which gave me $35$.
> Also, $7+28$ gave me the result of $35$.
> Then I set up an equation to find the missing node:
> $(79\times?)-(79+?)=7799$
> After solving the equation, I discovered that the $?$ was $101$.

Comment: Nice going on the algebra skills!

Comment: Thanks :) These nodes really gave my brain a proper workout!